# Existing function for seeing if a row exists in a data frame?

Tags: r

Is there an existing function for determining whether a row exists within a data frame?
I suppose could do an apply/identical, but it seems like I'm missing something.

For example:

given such a data frame:

```
  a   b
1 1 cat
2 2 dog
```

Is there an existing function which will allow me to test whether the row `(1, cat)` exists in the data frame?

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For data from @Marek answer.

```
nrow(merge(row_to_find,X))>0 # TRUE if exists
```

Comment: For me, this is also the fastest!

Comment: This can be dangerous. Make sure the row_to_find is a `data.frame`. Otherwise it will not look for matching the entire row. It works on the sample data by @Marek, as stated. But once you enter c(1,"cat") as the row_to_find it will return always true.

Answer (score 26):

Try `match_df` from plyr (using Marek's sample data):

```
library(plyr)
X <- data.frame(a=1:2, b=c("cat","dog"))
row_to_find <- data.frame(a=1, b="cat")

match_df(X, row_to_find)
```

Comment: Hmmm. I can't seem to find match_df in the plyr library.

Comment: Do you have the latest version?

Comment: great answer...thanks. Should be the accepted solution imho.

Answer (score 7):

Taking your example:

```
X <- data.frame(a=1:2, b=c("cat","dog"))
row_to_find <- data.frame(a=1, b="cat") # it has to be data.frame (not a vector) to hold different types
```

Then

```
duplicated(rbind(X, row_to_find))[nrow(X)+1]
```

gives you answer.

Comment: Thanks. I imagine duplicated might run a touch slower than apply though.

Comment: I'd expect duplicated to be considerably faster than apply

Comment: It is quite a bit faster. Off the top of my head I was thinking n vs n^2 comparisons. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For vector, y, with same number of elements as columns in dataframe, dfrm:

```
apply(dfrm, 1, function(x) all( x == y) )
```

Should return a vector of TRUE and FALSE which could in turn be used as an index in [,]

```
dfrm[ apply(dfrm, 1, function(x) all( x == y) ) , ]
```

The `identical` function is probably too stringent, since it will check attributes as well.

```
> y=c(1,2,3)
> x = data.frame(a=1:10, b=2:11, c=3:12)
> identical(x[1,] , y)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks. So no existing function? It seems like a pretty common problem.

Comment: You could use merge. With Marek's example, try:  `merge(x, row_to_find, 1,1)`

Comment: `all(x == y)` will be buggy because it will coerce x and y to be the same type.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Ben Bolker's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6326100/1973233) since `nrow(merge(row_to_find,X))>0` solution doesn't work for me (always give TRUE) :

```
tail(duplicated(rbind(X,row_to_find)),1)>0
```

Answer (score 1):

For fans of `dplyr` and the `tidyverse`, you can use `dplyr:anti_join()`. According to its documentation, `dplyr::anti_join(x, y)` "returns all rows from `x` where there are not matching values in `y`, keeping just columns from `x`." Hence for `dplyr::anti_join(row, df)` the result has zero rows, then `row` was indeed in `df`, if it has one row, then `row` was not in `df`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(~a, ~b,
              1,  "cat",
              2,  "dog")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       a b    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1  1.00 cat  
#> 2  2.00 dog

row <- tibble(a = 1, b = "cat")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       a b    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1  1.00 cat

nrow(anti_join(row, df)) == 0  # row is in df so should be TRUE
#> Joining, by = c("a", "b")
#> [1] TRUE

row <- tibble(a = 3, b = "horse")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       a b    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1  3.00 horse

nrow(anti_join(row, df)) == 0  # row is not in df so should be FALSE
#> Joining, by = c("a", "b")
#> [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using base R:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2), b = c("cat", "dog"))
any(df$a == 1 & df$b == "cat")
#> [1] TRUE
```