# Check whether a row with values belongs to a data frame in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Existing function for seeing if a row exists in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916854/existing-function-for-seeing-if-a-row-exists-in-a-data-frame)

Suppose I have the following data frame in R.

```
df = data.frame('a'=c(1:3), 'b'=c(4:6))
```

This data frame contains three rows: `(1,4), (2,5) and (3,6)`. Suppose I did not know which rows `df` contains and wanted to check whether a row (1,4) belongs to it, how can I check that?

My actual case involves comparison of 27 parameter values. Is there a solution in which I can do this without typing each and every parameter name? Thanks!

The reason I want to do this is that I have an R dataset called `masterdata` which contains simulation data. I want to update this data set with new data that is obtained as I make additional simulation runs with different parameter combinations. It is possible, however, that I may forget that I have run the simulation for a certain parameter combination and may run it again, in which case, the `masterdata` will be expanded with duplicate values. I can later go and remove these duplicate values, but I would not want the whole process of updating the data set to go through if the values are duplicate. For this I need to check if the data from a simulation run is already present in the `masterdata`. I can do this if I know how to check whether a given row belongs to the `masterdata`.

Thanks.

Comment: You might find some ideas in this earlier question: [Existing function for seeing if a row exists in a data frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916854/existing-function-for-seeing-if-a-row-exists-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: Thanks for the link Marek. Did not know about that thread.

Comment: There are two solutions there, one by you (which is similar to the one here) and one by Hadley. Is one faster than the other? Thanks.

Comment: @Curious2learn I think it's depends on data: number of rows, number of columns and types of columns.

Comment: @Curious2learn I run some tests and it seems that Hadley's is much faster (for wide data.frame ~3x faster).

Comment: I vote for reopen -- the true aim of the OP is remove duplicated rows, so this is a different question than the previous one.

Answer (score 6):

There may be more efficient ways, but I think

```
tail(duplicated(rbind(masterdata,newvals)),1)
```

will do it: in other words, attach the new row to the end of the data frame and see whether it is duplicated or not.

Comment: [I agree with your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916854/existing-function-for-seeing-if-a-row-exists-in-a-data-frame/5917042#5917042) ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare only two columns in the data.frame, then this does a trick:

```
> which(df$a+df$b*1i == 1+4i)
[1] 1
```

This may or may not be faster than other vectorized solution.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few ways to do this. You can use `ifelse()` which is a vectorized solution to return a boolean value for each row of your dataframe if it meets your conditions.

```
> with(df, ifelse(a == 1 & b == 4, 1, 0))
[1] 1 0 0
```

Since you are probably only interested in knowing whether your parameter combination has been run at all, you can wrap `sum()` around the previous command:

```
> sum(with(df, ifelse(a == 1 & b == 4, 1, 0)))
[1] 1
```

Another alternative is to use `nrow()` and `subset()`. We'll again use the `&` operator for our testing:

```
> nrow(subset(df, a == 1 & b == 4))
[1] 1
```

Comment: My actual case involves comparison of 27 parameter values. Is there a vectorized solution so that I do not have to type each and every parameter name? Thanks!

Comment: @Curious2learn - see @Ben's answer for the path to enlightenment. He's steering you in the right direction there.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need any more than a single unique call:

```
Test<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,2,2,3),b=c(1,2,2,3,3),c=(1,2,2,2,3))
Test
unique(Test) #Same with duplicated rows removed
```

Comment: That is not close to what OP asked :(