# R duplicated function not handling incomparables

Tags: r, duplicates

I'm trying to use `duplicated` to find rows in a dataframe that are duplicate based on two columns only.

When I pass anything into the `incomparables` argument, I get the error

```
dups = duplicated(data, incomparables="Age")
...
argument 'incomparables != FALSE' is not used (yet)
```

I can't figure this out.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692349/how-to-handle-argument-incomparables-false-is-not-used-yet) seems to have had a similar problem with no response.

No doubt there's a different way to do the same thing, which would also be good to know, as I am a beginner in R.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  If you answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, by reading the documentation of `?duplicated` you will realise that the `incomparables` argument accepts a vector of values that shouldn't be compared rather a column name, and I quote:

> a vector of values that cannot be compared.

And in more detail

> Values in incomparables will never be marked as duplicated. This is
>   intended to be used for a fairly small set of values and will not be
>   efficient for a very large set.

Either way, [the source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/duplicated.R#L29-L30) implies that you can't even use it even if you were following the documentation because this feature appears **to not been implemented yet**

```
if(!identical(incomparables, FALSE))    
   .NotYetUsed("incomparables != FALSE")
```

Though, back to your question, in order to run `duplicated` for two columns, you can explicitly name them, for example

```
duplicated(data[c("col1", "col2")]) ## (if the desired columns called col1 and col2)
```