# R comparing correlated values of one dataframe to those of another dataframe based on multiple keys

Tags: r

I have 2 data.frames of unequal dimensions:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), 
                   y = c("foo", "bar","wow"))
 df2 <- data.frame(x = c(2,2,5,7),
                   y = c("foo", "bar","wow","new"), 
                   z = c("this","is","weird","huh"))
```

Where, in `df1`, `x` values are correlated to `y` values.

I need to know how to compare `df2` to `df1` to verify that variables `x` and `y` are correct: values in `df2$x` and `df2$y` must match those of `df1`.

How can I get the rows of `df2` that show values that are either not in `df1` or that do not match the correlation between `x` and `y`?

So, from these two dataframes:

```
# df1  
# x   y  
# 1 foo  
# 2 bar  
# 3 wow

# df2 
# x   y     z
# 2 foo  this  
# 2 bar    is  
# 5 wow weird  
# 7 new   huh
```

I would like to get a result like:

```
# badRows
# x   y     z
# 2 foo  this  
# 5 wow weird  
# 7 new   huh
```

I've tried using `identical()` and `compare()` with no luck.

Update: Provisional answer was found here (however using the multiple keys at the moment was not clear until after this question was posted): [Find complement of a data frame (anti - join)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702960/find-complement-of-a-data-frame-anti-join)

Comment: Tried `%in%` and `merge`?

Comment: Well, as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916854/existing-function-for-seeing-if-a-row-exists-in-a-data-frame), I could use `plyr::match_df()` to get the rows that are right, but I can't get it to get those that I don't want.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I did try `merge` and `%in%` but no luck.

Comment: Try `dplyr::anti_join(df2, df1)`

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!
I never found that other post before posting this one!

Comment: use data.table/dplyr could solve it: data.table::data.table(df2, key=c('x','y'))[!data.table(df1, key=c('x','y'))]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?dplyr::anti_join` -- an `anti_join` will return all rows from `x` where there are not matching values in `y` and keep just the columns from `x`:

```
library(dplyr)

anti_join(df2, df1, by = c("x", "y"))
#   x   y     z
# 1 2 foo  this
# 2 5 wow weird
# 3 7 new   huh
```