# Function to check if identical row, date minus 1 exists

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd need a function that checks my data frame for an otherwise identical row, but with date minus 1, and returns `true` if it exists. It's a large data frame, so I'd like to do it as efficiently as possible.

For example, take the following data frame:

```
name  |date       
Timmy |01/Jan/2016
Timmy |02/Jan/2016
Timmy |03/Jan/2016
Sally |04/Jan/2016
Johnny|13/Feb/2016
Johnny|29/Mar/2016
```

The function should see `Timmy|02/Jan/2016`, check if `Timmy|01/Jan/2016` exists, and return `true`.  The resulting data frame would look like this:

```
name  |date       |hasDateMinusOne
Timmy |01/Jan/2016|false
Timmy |02/Jan/2016|true
Timmy |03/Jan/2016|true
Sally |04/Jan/2016|false
Johnny|13/Feb/2016|false
Johnny|29/Mar/2016|false
```

[This is the closest answer I've found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916854/existing-function-for-seeing-if-a-row-exists-in-a-data-frame)  Although it was answered by Hadley, it's 5 years old and predates dplyr.  I'm wondering if it's still the most efficient way to handle 1,000,000+ rows.

Thanks!

Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you format `date` as a date, you can just subtract one:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(name) %>% 
    mutate(date = as.Date(date, '%d/%b/%Y'), 
           hasDateMinusOne = (date - 1) %in% date)

# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
# Groups: name [3]
# 
#     name       date hasDateMinusOne
#   (fctr)     (date)           (lgl)
# 1  Timmy 2016-01-01           FALSE
# 2  Timmy 2016-01-02            TRUE
# 3  Timmy 2016-01-03            TRUE
# 4  Sally 2016-01-04           FALSE
# 5 Johnny 2016-02-13           FALSE
# 6 Johnny 2016-03-29           FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using only `base R`.  Convert the 'date' to 'Date' class using `transform`, then with `ave` we group by 'name' and find whether the day before is found `%in%` the 'date' column.

```
df <- transform(df, date = as.Date(date, "%d/%b/%Y"))
df$hasDateMinusOne <- with(df, !!ave(as.integer(date), name,
            FUN = function(x) (x-1) %in% x))
```

---

If efficiency matters, another option is `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), change 'date' to 'Date' class, grouped by 'name' we find whether the previous day is found `%in%` the 'date' column.

```
setDT(df)[, date := as.Date(date, '%d/%b/%Y') 
     ][, hasDateMinusOne := (date-1) %in% date, by =  name]
df
#     name       date hasDateMinusOne
#1:  Timmy 2016-01-01           FALSE
#2:  Timmy 2016-01-02            TRUE
#3:  Timmy 2016-01-03            TRUE
#4:  Sally 2016-01-04           FALSE
#5: Johnny 2016-02-13           FALSE
#6: Johnny 2016-03-29           FALSE
```