# R Efficient way to create new data frame from unique rows between two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I need to create a new data frame two existing data frames where the new data frame is each row from the first data frame that is not in the second data frame.  I found some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916854/existing-function-for-seeing-if-a-row-exists-in-a-data-frame) using the merge function that allowed me to do it this way.  Basically, if the resulting merge has a result then the row is in the data frame and I don't add it to my new one:

```
for (j in 1:nrow(my.df)) {
    if(nrow(merge(my.df[j,],sample.df))==0) {
        test.df <- rbind(test.df,my.df[j,])
    }
}
```

The problem is that the for loop is very slow.  Is there a more efficient way to build a data frame given the constraints I have?

`my.df`

```
A B class
1 2 x
2 3 y
3 4 z
```

`sample.df`

```
A B class
1 2 x
```

`test.df` should look like

```
A B class
2 3 y
3 4 z
```

Comment: look at `?dplyr::setdiff()` and `?dplyr::anti_join()` for help beyond that please post a reproducible example with ideal output :)

Comment: The code is reproducible, you just need two data frames and you will get the desired output that I am looking for (the code works as is).  I am just looking for a faster way.

Comment: what does `my.df` look like? how about `sample.df`?

Comment: I have included an example of what a data frame looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `library(dplyr)` we can use `anti_join()`:

```
anti_join(my.df, sample.df)
# Joining, by = c("A", "B", "class")
#   A B class
# 1 3 4     z
# 2 2 3     y
```

As mentioned by @Gregor, you can also convert your `data.frames` into `data.tables` with `library(data.table)` to get some extra quickness

Comment: This works.  There was noticeable speedup.  Enough for now.  I will try converting to a table for even more speed.

Comment: yes if you specify `anti_join(..., by = c("variable1, variable2))`, the warning is there to show which columns it is choosing to match on, which is by default all common names shared between the two data.frames